# How to calculate an average value from categorical data?

Tags: excel, statistics, average, survey

I have a survey data looks like this:

| No. of Respondents | Reported height |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | <165 |
| 77 | 166-170 |
| 218 | 171-175 |
| 236 | 176-180 |
| 327 | 181+ |

I want to calculate the average height of the respondents in Excel. What kind of formula should I apply?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to first decide whether the respondents who have a height of <165 should be classed as precisely 165, or else refine the group to include an estimate for the lower bound, e.g. 140-165. Similarly for 181+.

Comment: This is a surprisingly subtle question (well, I was surprised, anyway). The most nearly right thing to do is to estimate parameters for a distribution to fit these data, which are said to be "interval censored" (a web search will find resources about that). In general that's not altogether simple, but a pretty good approximation is to just compute a weighted average, assuming that all measurements that fall into a bin have the same value. For the bins of the form a < x < b, you can assume x = (b + a)/2.

Comment: For the bins at the end, x < 165 on the left and x >= 181 on the right, you'll have to assume a typical value. Maybe 150 and 196, respectively? This is a guess at the average value for items in those bins -- obviously you can guess different things. To avoid guessing, one would have to take censoring into account, and that makes the problem more complex as I was saying.

Comment: On a side note, it looks like your table is cumulative, i.e., the number for each succeeding bin includes the numbers for all the preceding bins. You'll probably want to rewrite that so that each bin has just the number for that bin alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a very subtle question. Let me first discuss my thoughts and solution before posting the code.

- As expected, there will be quite some respondents with a reported height of more than 180cm (I hope I'm interpreting the question correctly and these are heights in cm). For about a third of the respondents we thus have very little information about their actual height. If we would assume a typical value for all these respondents, then this (somewhat arbitrary) assumption will have a large impact on the outcome. As suggested by @RobertDodier, it's probably better to fit a distribution to the data and let this distribution extrapolate into the tails.
- The height distribution of a population is often considered to be well-approximated by a normal distribution (especially if different normal distributions are used for male and female heights). I'm not sure whether this additional information is available from your survey data. If yes, you might exploit this info. This info being absent I will consider a single normal distribution.

It remains to find the normal distribution with a good fit to your interval-censored data. Given the normality assumption, I compute the maximum likelihood estimator as follows:

1. For a given mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution, we can calculate the probability for each of the intervals. This leads to 5 probabilities.
2. If the data is a random sample of respondents, then the data follows a categorical distribution and the log-likelihood can be computed. There is only one twist. The five probabilities are jointly specified by the two parameters of the normal distribution (mean and standard deviation).
3. Let a numerical optimiser minimise the negative log-likelihood.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Input characteristics (as column vectors)
#NumberOfRespondents = np.array([[40],[70],[218],[236],[327]])
NumberOfRespondents = np.array([[40],[77],[218],[236],[327]])
HeightCutOff = np.array([[165],[170],[175],[180]])

# Number of intervals
L = len(HeightCutOff)+1

# Compute probabilities for given mu and sigma
def NormalProbabilities(ParaVector):
    mu = ParaVector[0]
    sigma = ParaVector[1]

    # Compute interval probabilities
    ProbList = np.zeros((L, 1))
    for i in range(L):
        # Probability for (-inf,165)
        if i==0:
            ProbList[i] = norm.cdf(HeightCutOff[0], loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        # Probability for (180,inf)
        elif i==(L-1):
            ProbList[i] = 1-norm.cdf(HeightCutOff[-1], loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        # Other probabilities
        else:
            ProbList[i] = norm.cdf(HeightCutOff[i], loc=mu, scale=sigma)-norm.cdf(HeightCutOff[i-1], loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    # Output
    return ProbList

# Compute loglikelihood for given mu and sigma
def minusLogLikelihood(ParaVector):
    # Compute interval probabilities
    plist = NormalProbabilities(ParaVector)

    # Compute log-likelihood
    LogLik = np.sum(NumberOfRespondents*np.log(plist))
    return -LogLik

# Optimization negative likelihood
ParaStart = [170, 20];
OptimizerBounds = [(-np.inf, np.inf), (0.01, np.inf)]
OptimResult = minimize(minusLogLikelihood, ParaStart, method="Nelder-Mead", bounds=OptimizerBounds)

# Report results
print('\nMean estimate: ', OptimResult.x[0])
print('Std estimate: ', OptimResult.x[1], '\n')

print('Empirical probabilites: ', (NumberOfRespondents/np.sum(NumberOfRespondents)).T)
print('Estimated probabilities: ', (NormalProbabilities(OptimResult.x)).T, '\n')

print('True category counts: ', NumberOfRespondents.T)
print('Estimated category counts: ', (NormalProbabilities(OptimResult.x)*np.sum(NumberOfRespondents)).T)
```

These are the outputs:

```
Mean estimate:  177.50905604361458
Std estimate:  7.118910358800334 

Empirical probabilites:  [[0.04454343 0.0857461  0.24276169 0.26280624 0.36414254]]
Estimated probabilities:  [[0.03944537 0.10631209 0.21649315 0.27454448 0.36320491]] 

True category counts:  [[ 40  77 218 236 327]]
Estimated category counts:  [[ 35.42194412  95.46825299 194.41085156 246.54094083 326.1580105 ]]
```

In conclusion, based on the normality assumption your average height would be 177.5cm. The fit of the data seems OK (but not amazing).

PS1: I don't have access to Excel. I hope the explanations might help you to translate the code to Excel.
PS2: There are differences of 1 between the upper bound of an interval and the lower bound of the next interval. As such, I'm not completely sure to which the interval the remaining values should be contributed (say values within 165 and 166). You might want to change the HeightCutfOff array if needed.